# Using java with mapinfo for integrated mapping?

Tags: mapinfo, java

Can we use integrated mapping with java? Are there any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrated Mapping uses OLE, so can only support languages that support this. Delphi, VB, C and C++ are all used (I have used all of these with it), powerbuilder too.

I think the limitations are that you have to be able to have an application with a front window as such.

The only way I can it being able to be used, is with a C++ (or another) 'bridge' between the java and MapBasic.  It's not the work of a beginner, lets say that now.  I can't see you being able to use Java and MapBasic without a bridge of som sorts, passing over a handle.

Answer (score 0):

By using a Java-COM bridge you can. Some time ago I made a successful experiment for this. I  wrote a sample Eclipse project and put it on my BLOG page at:

http://mustafaozcetin.wordpress.com/integrated-mapping/java-mapinfo-ile-integrated-mapping/

The page is in Turkish but you can use Google Translator. You can download the sample project from the bottom of the page.